# How to get stacked UITextFields in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield, uistoryboard

On the iTunes Connect login screen the username and password labels are stack onto of each other and are curved on the top and flat in the middle (screenshot below). **Is it possible to achieve this in the Xcode 7.2 Storyboard?** Or this is just a complicated thing only Apple can do?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have implemented a very similar UI for an app I built. The solution I came up with is to combine multiple elements to achieve the desired interface. I did this all in a Storyboard with a little bit of complimentary code, but of course it could be done all in code as well.

I used a `UIView` with a fixed width and height as the "container" box which I centered horizontally. I then added the Email (Apple ID) and Password `UILabel`s to this container view, aligned them on the left, and stacked them to fill the height of the container. I added the separator line `UIView` with a 1pt height in between the two labels, aligning its leading and trailing to its container view. Then, add the two `UITextField`s, constraining them such that they align to the top and bottom of their relevant labels, the leading is set to the label's trailing, and the trailing aligns with the container view's trailing. Add any padding where seen fit.

The only thing that must be done programmatically is to apply a border to the container view and round the edges:

```
self.loginContainerView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
self.loginContainerView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
self.loginContainerView.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
```

[image]

[image]

Not too bad! Perhaps this could be even easier if you use `UIStackView`.

Comment: Works perfect thank you! Took all of my `UITextFields` (5 to be exact) embedded them in a UIView and performed your 3 lines on that `UIView`. May have been easier on a `UIStackView` but I haven't used one of those yet.